# C# Logic wont work

Tags: c#, if-statement, logic

im new to C# and my logic wont work
it keeps on displaying my else command
there is no errors

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        int age = 12;
        if ((age <= 0) && (age >= 12))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are young");
        }
        else if ((age <= 13) && (age >= 17))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You're a teen");
        }
        else if ((age <= 18) && (age >= 50))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You're an adult");
        }
        else if ((age <= 51) && (age >= 120))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You're Elderly");
        }else
        {
            Console.Beep();
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: How can someone be both less than `0` and older than `12`? All of your conditions are impossible.

Comment: [C# Operators documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx)

Comment: Try this: `((age >= 0) && (age <= 12))`

Comment: It is easy to remember: Where the two flanks of the ">" or "<" are open (= great distance) is the "greater than"-side. Where they meet (= small distance) is the "less than"-side of the inequality.

Comment: You've got your `>` and `<` back to front.  Easy way to remember `<` is that it looks like an **L** as in **less than**

Answer (score 2):

You just need to swap your conditions for ***every age range***:

```
int age = 12;
if ((age >= 0) && (age <= 12))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You are young");
}
else if ((age >= 13) && (age <= 17))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You're a teen");
}
else if ((age >= 18) && (age <= 50))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You're an adult");
}
else if ((age >= 51) && (age <= 120))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You're Elderly");
}
else
{
    Console.Beep();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int age = 12;
if ((age >= 0) && (age <= 12))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You are young");
}
else if ((age >= 13) && (age <= 17))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You're a teen");
}
else if ((age >= 18) && (age <= 50))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You're an adult");
}
else if ((age >= 51) && (age <= 120))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You're Elderly");
}else
{
    Console.Beep();
}
```

1. There is nothing wrong with syntax but your logic
2. Take a look at all <= condition.

Answer (score 1):

The conditions within the if statements aren't correct, try this:

```
int age = 12;

if ((age >= 0) && (age <= 12))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You are young");
}
else if ((age >= 13) && (age <= 17))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You're a teen");
}
else if ((age >= 18) && (age <= 50))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You're an adult");
}
else if ((age >= 51) && (age <= 120))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You're Elderly");
}
else
{
    Console.Beep();
}
```